# Ejecutar eventos con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-input").on("input", function(){
        $(".div-tags").show();
    });

    $(".div-tags a").on("click", function(){
        var Optag = $(this).text() + "," + $(this).attr("data-id");
        $(".main-input").focus();
        $(".main-input").val(Optag);
        return false;
    });

    $(".main-input").on('input', function(){
          alert($(this).val());   
    });
});
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando de click sobre un enlace, se coloque texto en el input y enseguida se ejecute el evento que tiene asignado ese input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando me encontré con la función trigger, que ejecuta todos los controladores y comportamientos adjuntos a los elementos coincidentes para el tipo de evento dado.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-input").on("input", function(){
        $(".div-tags").show();
    });

    $(".div-tags a").on("click", function(){
        var Optag = $(this).text() + "," + $(this).attr("data-id");
        $(".main-input").val(Optag);
        $(".main-input").trigger("input");
        return false;
    });

    $(".main-input").on('input', function(){
          alert($(this).val());   
    });
});
```